# Laravel: How to Validate Field in Modal?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm still new in Laravel. When I want to register the users by using modal, the modal will be closed if I click button submit even though there is no record have been filled in. When I open back the modal, no error message appeared but when I do inspect, it says `errors: {name: ["Name is required"],`. Supposedly I want to make the modal stays with error message says `Name field is required`. How can I do that? Here I show some of the code.

**index.blade.php**

**-- Add User Modal --**

```
<div id="add-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #286090;">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="add-modal-title" style="color: #fff"></h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name" style="text-align: left;">Name<p style="color:#e32; font-weight: bold; display:inline;">*</p></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                            <p class="errorName text-danger hidden"></p>
                        </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
             <div class="add-modal-footer modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn action-btn" data-dismiss="modal">
                     <span class='fa' id='footer-action-btn'></span>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                     <span class='fa fa-remove'></span> Close
                  </button>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**-- Add User Jquery --**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.add-admin', function() {
        $("#form").trigger("reset");
        $('.errorName').addClass('hidden');
        $('.action-btn').addClass('btn-primary');
        $('.action-btn').addClass('add');
        $('.action-btn').removeClass('edit');
        $('#footer-action-btn').addClass('fa-plus');
        $('#footer-action-btn').text(' Add');
        $('.add-modal-title').text('Add Admin');
        $('#add-modal').modal('show');
    });

    $('.add-modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{url("/admin/create")}}',
            data: {
                '_token': $('#token').val(),
                'name': $('#name').val(),
            },

             success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if((data.errors))
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#admin-modal').modal('show');
                    },100);

                    if(data.errors.name)
                    {
                        $('.errorName').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorName').text(data.errors.name);
                    }
                    if(!data.errors.name)
                    {
                        $('.errorName').addClass('hidden');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
                    toastr.success("Successfully added "+data.name,'Success', {timeOut: 2000});
                    //Update the table row
                    $('#admin-table').append("<tr class='admin"+data.id+"'><td>"+data.id+"</td><td>"+data.name+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm edit-admin' data-content='"+data.id+","+data.name+"'>Edit</button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-admin' data-content='"+data.id+","+data.name+"'>Delete</button></td></tr>");

                }
            }
        });
    });
 

</script
```

**AdminController.php**

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'name'=>'required',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'Name is required',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make ( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );
        if ($validator->fails ())
        {
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag ()->toArray ()));
        }
        else
        {
            //Insert to table Admins
            $admins = Admin::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
            ]);

            return response()->json($admins);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you have more than one  html element with id `name`

Comment: print request data before validator call `dd($request->all())` and make sure `name` filed input is coming in request data.